# Not able to delete or find records by id in mongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, rest, angular6, mongorepository

I am saving customer records in Mongo DB, i am using Angular 6 as a front end.
While saving, i am not sending Id value, so automatically Mongo is creating id and saving records.

I am using MongoRepository in Java for saving. But while doing "deleteById" or "findById", its not able to search or delete those records.

Can you help.

Angular Customer Model

---

```
export interface Customer {
    id : string,
    custId : number,
    customerName : string,
    email: string,
    phone : string,
    age: number,
    city : string,
    state : string,
    createdDate : Date
}
```

User.service.ts

---

```
deleteCustomerData(id): Observable<Customer>{
    console.log(this.deleteCustomerUrl  + id);
    return this.http.delete<Customer>(this.deleteCustomerUrl + id);
  }
```

Java Controller

---

```
@DeleteMapping("/deleteCustomer/{id}")
    public String deleteCustomerById(@PathVariable String id) {
        //ObjectId objId = new ObjectId(id);
        customerService.deleteCustomerById(id);
        return "deleted customer by id"+ id;
    }
```

Java Service

---

```
public void deleteCustomerById(String id) {
        customerRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
```

Java Model

---

```
@Document(collection="Customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id

    private String Id;

    private String customerName;
    private int age;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private int custId;

}
```

Java Repository

---

```
package com.tivo.extract.config.repository;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

import com.tivo.extract.config.model.Customer;

public interface CustomerRepository extends MongoRepository<Customer, String>{

}
```

Comment: Please check you have send DELETE request to the API server from front end.
If this not a case please attach the exception or log when the request triggered.

Comment: No exception, what ever I'd I am sending...there is no match in db...but no exception.

Comment: That I'd is present in db and from UI I am able to send that id but don't know why it is not finding. May be due to it's an objectId or something.

Comment: java side everything is correct please check on angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the data type of primary field need to be changed from String to ObjectId.
**Mongo db uses ObjecId as primary key type by default.**

Answer (score 0):

This is a late response but I solved this issue by changing `private String Id` to `private String id`. Seems like it is only a naming problem.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution you have to make the field (ex. Email Id, name,last name) which you want to use as a key annote it with @Id annotation in the class

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).